# Как из одной даты вычесть другую?

Tags: php, дата

Друзья, подскажите, пожалуйста, как из 1 даты вычесть другую, что бы вплоть до дней.
У меня стоит задача, есть день рождение 01.09.1995 и надо написать сколько мне лет, то есть сделать вычитание текущей даты от дня рождения и вывести столько лет.

Просто вычесть года я могу - но надо вплоть до дней. Заранее спасибо.

```
<?
$happyday = "09.01.1995";
$curday = date(d.m.Y);
// вычитание дат, вам столько то лет.
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
$happyday = "09.01.1995";
$curday = date('d.m.Y');
$d1 = strtotime($happyday);
$d2 = strtotime($curday);
$diff = $d2-$d1;
$diff = $diff/(60*60*24*365);
$years = floor($diff);
```

Answer (score 7):

[DateTime::diff](http://php.net/datetime.diff)

> `date_diff` — Returns the difference between two `DateTime` objects

Пример:

```
$years = date_diff(new DateTime("09.01.1995"), new DateTime())->y;
// или
$years = date_create()->diff(date_create("09.01.1995"))->y;
```

Answer (score 1):

Расщепить входящие даты на массивы через `explode()`, применить `mktime()` для получения `unix timestamp`, найти разницу, разделить на 24 * 60 * 60

Comment: да, я догадывался делал через strtotime но не получается